# How can I get Heroku's SSL functionality, certs:auto, to work for my non-www domain?

Tags: ssl, heroku

Supposedly, this command should automagically setup SSL for your domain:

```
heroku certs:auto:enable
```

This worked fine for my domain "www.example.io" but not "example.io".  Is there something special I have to do for this?  Here's the output:

```
➜  ExamPleGit.clean git:(master) heroku certs:auto
=== Automatic Certificate Management is enabled on example

Certificate details:
Common Name(s): www.example.io
Expires At:     2018-01-22 15:04 UTC
Issuer:         /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Starts At:      2017-10-24 15:04 UTC
Subject:        /CN=www.example.io
SSL certificate is verified by a root authority.

Domain          Status
──────────────  ────────────
www.example.io  DNS Verified
example.io      Failing

=== Some domains are failing validation, please verify that your DNS matches: heroku domains
➜  ExamPleGit.clean git:(master) heroku domains
=== example Heroku Domain
example.herokuapp.com

=== example Custom Domains
Domain Name     DNS Record Type  DNS Target
──────────────  ───────────────  ────────────────────────────
www.example.io  CNAME            www.example.io.herokudns.com
example.io      ALIAS or ANAME   example.io.herokudns.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this was to simply redirect all traffic from example.io -> www.example.io in my domain providers control panel, so I didn't need to worry about SSL for that URL.  For Namecheap, go to the Advanced DNS settings of your domain and add this entry:

URL Redirect Record     @   http://www.example.io/

Once that is done, then you can then setup node or PHP (via .htaccess file) to force all http -> https and give yourself an SSL secure site.